# Will gdisk or sgdisk commands delete my data? (mdadm e-mail alert)

Tags: command-line, partitioning, raid, mdadm, gdisk

I currently try to fix my mdadm /dev/md0 raid5 partition. I was informed via e-mail notification from mdadm e-mail alerts that there is a fail event and a DegradedArray event. I found this as a possible solution to the probblem of mine: https://superuser.com/a/1442762/1797988

The answer in the question looks promising because I can apply it successfully to a copy of this disk. I just have no clue what exactly the bash commands `gdisk` and `sgdisk` are doing to it. And I want to know, if it will harm the accessibality of the data?

If I am going to execute these commands to my hard drive, will I be able to still access my data without the need of any additional Linux magic to recover something?

I haven't touched anything so far because the data are really important to me. It would be nice to fix the problem, but not for the cost of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes these applications can cause you to lose your data.

Data that isn't sufficiently backed up is subject to being lost at any moment.
But risk of data loss is heightened when you are making changes to partition schemes, partitions, file systems, etc.  For example, what if you make a mistake?

Risk of data loss is *never* zero percent. Even something with a very low chance of happening will become an inevitability given enough time.

Comment: That's very diplomatical. But will using the commands in the correct way by default harm my data partition?

Comment: Yes it could. The fact that you have to "fix" anything means it's already broken. These tools could cause data loss even if you use them correctly. Back up whatever you don't want to lose.